# Exclude the match for the special character # and all the characters after # within a regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure it out how to exclude the special character # + the last characters after the special character #.

Below my regular expression:

```
(http|https):\/\/[www.]*website.com\/menu\/sub_menu\/sub_sub_menu\/.*
```

This regex can match these strings where the final part of the string can change all the time:

```
https://website.com/menu/sub_menu/sub_sub_menu/4e132072-90b2-4366-bcec-72575e412174
https://www.website.com/menu/sub_menu/sub_sub_menu/4e132072-943254b2-4453466-ywebf3
```

What I would like **to exclude from the match** are all the string that contains at the end the special character like # followed by any possible character or a specific string.

Like the examples below:

```
https://website.com/menu/sub_menu/sub_sub_menu/4e132072-90b2-4366-bcec-72575e412174#page1
https://website.com/menu/sub_menu/sub_sub_menu/4e132072-90b2-4366-bcec-72575e412174#page2
https://website.com/menu/sub_menu/sub_sub_menu/4e132072-90b2-4366-bcec-72575e412174#any_string
```

I know that for exclude some characters I can user the `^` but i'm not sure about how to properly use it.

Comment: Try `^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?website\.com\/menu\/sub_menu\/sub_sub_menu\/[^#]*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^((?:http|https):\/\/(?:www\.)?website.com\/menu\/sub_menu\/sub_sub_menu\/)([^#]*)(.*)$
```

You will get 3 capture groups back:

Group 1 will contain the static URL part

Group 2 will contain the dynamic part

Group 3 will contain # followed by the rest.

You can simply concatenate Group 1 and 2 in your favorite programming language to get the full URL without the #-part.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it seems not working within the regex tester: https://regexr.com/4onqq

Comment: Try again now, there was a bug with your original www part that I took over, I just fixed it.

Comment: You can try it too. But it seems that it'd doesn't match any of the following strings.

Comment: I just tried it, it works - but your example text on the tester site needs to be just 1 URL, not a text and a bunch of URLs, since regex is line-based it will fail the anchors otherwise. See: https://regexr.com/4onsa